# Remove Object when Collision Detected in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision, removechild

I'm making a game where your player (gun) shoots enemies (baddie) to gain score. I've set it up so you have three lives (lives) until it is game over. I am trying to add an addLife function that works by when your player collects an object (waterMelon), it gets a life. I have added a timer event that runs the function addLife, that adds an instance of the Movie clip to the stage every 5 seconds. In that function, ive created another function called checkCollisions, that is meant to check the collision of the player, to the object, remove the object from the stage, then add a life.

```
var timer2:Timer = new Timer(5000);

timer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addLife);
timer2.start();
var watermelon:waterMelon = new waterMelon();

function addLife(evt:TimerEvent):void{
    watermelon.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    watermelon.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

    addChild(watermelon);
    watermelon.push(waterMelon);

    checkCollision();
}

function checkCollision(){
    if (gun.hitTestObject(watermelon)){
    removeChild(watermelon);
    lives++;
    livesDisplay.gotoAndStop(livesDisplay.currentFrame-1);
    }
}
```

The only part of the code that works is the adding the watermelon to the stage, but when my player collides with it, it does not remove from the stage. Could someone please tell me how I make my watermelon completely be removed from the stage when the player collides with it, and add a life to my player. Once again, each object equals this; **gun** = player, **waterMelon** = object/watermelon, **lives** = lives, **livesDisplay** = physical display of lives.

Comment: What does the watermelon.push(waterMelon); mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to delete the array(watermelon) from the stage instead of the object(waterMelon). Although by the looks you are using arrays so you will have to find the index of the object colliding with the gun from the array watermelon. You do this with a for loop.

```
for (melonCount:int = 0; melonCount>watermelon.length;melonCount--)
{
 if (gun.hitTestObject(watermelon[melonCount]))
 {
  removeChild(watermelon[melonCount])
  watermelon.splice(melonCount, 1)
  melonCount--
 }
}
```